# Is there any history for master branch policy changes?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We've structured our environment such that the main approval in ADO exists at the master branch policy level, where a 2nd user must approve the pull request prior to merging to the master branch. From there it's mostly automated testing, and approvals in ServiceNow. To help address SOD concerns, we're wondering if you had insight into either of the following:

1. Is there any history for master branch policy changes? We've seen the pipeline approval history before, but I'm not sure if there's anything similar that tracks changes to the policy configurations.
2. Is there any reporting out of ADO that would show a population of merges and include the owner of the change and the approver? The thought being that this could be used to ensure no one merged their own code without independent approval.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there any history for master branch policy changes?

Yes, while there isn't something like a *History* tab available for Branch policies, there are **Audit events** you can access and consume from the `Auditing` tab in the `Organization Settings` page. Auditing for Azure Repos events was announced around the [July 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-154-update#auditing-for-azure-repos-events) timeframe.

The auditing page provides a simple view into the audit events recorded for your organization. This data is also available to export in a `CSV` or `JSON` format. The **Policy** area covers the changes made to branch policies. You can view events for policies when they are created, removed, modified, or bypassed.

Here is an example of what that looks like:

[image: Auditing tab in Azure DevOps]

Clicking on the `i` button available for each event will also give you more details about the exact change that was made, for example, changing the minimum approver count from `2` to `3`.

> 2. Is there any reporting out of ADO that would show a population of merges and include the owner of the change and the approver? The thought being that this could be used to ensure **no one merged their own code** without independent approval.

There's an even better option. :) If you intend to enforce this, you should do it with a **branch policy** rather than a report:

[image: Branch policy]

While configuring the [Require a minimum number of reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#require-a-minimum-number-of-reviewers) branch policy, you can ensure this with the following options:

- If **Allow requestors to approve their own changes** is selected, the creator of the pull request may vote on its approval. If not, they can still vote Approve on their pull request, but their vote won't count toward the Minimum number of reviewers.
- By default, anyone with push permissions on the source branch may both add commits and vote on the pull request's approval. By enabling **Prohibit the most recent pusher from approving their own changes**, you can enforce segregation of duties - having the most recent push automatically makes the pusher's vote not count.

Hope this addresses your requirement.

References:

- [Access, export, and filter audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)
- [Improve code quality with branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops)